# How to split minutes into days, hours and minutes in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-conversion

I have a column which consist of minutes. Is there any simple way to split minutes column into one column which shows days, hours, minutes only?

```
DURATION              
-----------
67           ==> 1 hour, 7 minutes
1507         ==> 1 day, 1 hour, 7 minutes
23           ==> 23 minutes
```

I googled for solution but I didn't find any solution similar for me. I want to show this in a report but trying to find how can I solve this column looks meaningfully. Duration column's calculation like this.

```
avg(datediff(MINUTE, ei.SentDate, eo.SentDate)) over(partition by ei.mailbox) as DURATION
```

Comment: If `minutes` is your number of minutes, `minutes%60` will give you the minutes only, `(minutes/60)%24` will give you hours only, `minutes/(60*24)` will give you days only. (hint: % is the modulo operator, giving remainder after division) Now do some fancy string concatenation/formatting :)

Answer (score 10):

A google search landed me here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic490411-8-1.aspx

and It says... which I just tested working ...

```
Declare @theMinutes int
Set @theMinutes = 67 

Select @theMinutes / 1440 as NoDays  -- 1440 minutes per day 
       , (@theMinutes % 1440) / 60 as NoHours -- modulo 1440 
       , (@theMinutes % 60) as NoMinutes -- modulo 60
```

Answer (score 4):

```
create FUNCTION  fun_Date_Friendly (@minutes int)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
   return CASE 
    when @minutes < 60 then cast( @minutes as varchar(10)) + ' Min'
    when @minutes < 1440 then cast(@minutes/60 as varchar(10)) + ' Hr, ' + cast(@minutes%60 as varchar(10)) + ' Min'
    else cast(@minutes/(1440 ) as varchar(10)) + ' Days, ' + cast((@minutes%1440 )/60 as varchar(10)) + ' Hr, ' + cast(((@minutes%1440 )%60) as varchar(10)) + ' Min'
    end
end
go
```

then just pass minutes to function

```
select  dbo.fun_Date_Friendly(20) val
```