# scalar function for date formatting

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a column which contains time in minutes. What I am looking to do is create a function that returns the following formats:

```
0 = NULL
>0 and <60 mins = '##min'
between 60 mins & 1440 mins = '##hr,##min'
>1440mins = '##days,##hr,##min'
```

I've managed to get some of this done using the function below however I'm struggling with how to split days, hours and minutes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Format_Date_Friendly 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @minutes int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(100)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Result = CASE WHEN @minutes = 0 THEN ''
            WHEN @minutes <= 60 THEN CAST(@minutes AS nvarchar(100)) + ' min' 
          WHEN @minutes BETWEEN 60 AND 1440 THEN CAST(CAST(@minutes/60 AS INT) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' hr'
           ELSE NULL end

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: Which portions are you struggling with? Can you explain exactly what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - there's nothing wrong with the code I've posted above, apart from the fact it only returns either minutes or hours. What I'm trying to achieve is something more specific, so if my data has 125 minutes, I want it to return '2hr5min' and so on...

Comment: Any special handling for pluralization?  e.g., do you want to return `days` plural for everything over 1440 minutes, or just when there are more than 2880 minutes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split minutes into days, hours and minutes in tsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352607/how-to-split-minutes-into-days-hours-and-minutes-in-tsql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece-by-piece approach might be a bit more readable than the current "one expression to do everything" format - the code below will build up the expression one piece at a time, starting with the largest (days) and going down to the minute level.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Format_Date_Friendly 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @minutes int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(10) = ''


    IF @minutes > 1440 
      BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@minutes/1440 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' days, '
      END

    IF @minutes > 60 
      BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + CAST((@minutes%1440) /60 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' hr, '
      END

    IF @minutes > 0
      BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + CAST(@minutes % 60 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' min'
      END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Format_Date_Friendly (@minutes int)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
   return CASE 
    when @minutes < 60 then cast( @minutes as varchar(10)) + 'min'
    when @minutes < 1400 then cast(@minutes/60 as varchar(10)) + 'hr, ' + cast(@minutes%60 as varchar(10)) + 'min'
    else cast(@minutes/(1400) as varchar(10)) + 'days, ' + cast((@minutes%1400)/60 as varchar(10)) + 'hr, ' + cast(((@minutes%1400)%60) as varchar(10)) + 'min'
    end
end
go
```

**Demo**

```
;with data(d) as (
    select 0 d union all
    select 45 d union all
    select 80 union all
    select 1800
)
select d, dbo.udf_Format_Date_Friendly(d) val
from data
```

**OutPut**

```
0   0min
45  45min
80  1hr, 20min
1800    1days, 6hr, 40min
```